# Apache .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my situation. I have a web root and several subdirectories, let's say:

```
/var/www
/var/www/site1
/var/www/site2
```

Due to certain limitations, I need the ability to keep one single domain and have separate folders like this. This will work fine for me, but many JS and CSS references in both sites point to things like:

```
"/js/file.js"
"/css/file.css"
```

Because these files are referenced absolutely, they are looking for the 'js' and 'css' directories in /var/www, which of course does not exist. Is there a way to use RewriteRules to redirect requests for absolutely referenced files to point to the correct subdirectory? I have tried doing things like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /site1
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*)$ /site1/js/$1
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ /site1/css/$1
```

But neither of these work, even redirecting to only one directory, not to mention handling both site1 and site2. Is what I'm trying possible?

EDIT: SOLUTION

I ended up adapting Jon's advice to fit my situation. I have the ability to programatically make changes to my .htaccess file whenever a new subdirectory is added or removed. For each "site" that I want, I have the following section in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} sitename=site1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1 [L]
```

Index.php is a file that lists all my sites, deletes the "sitename" cookie, and sets a cookie of "sitename=site#" when a particular one is selected. My RewriteConds check,

1. If the request is not for /
2. If the request is not for /index.php
3. If the request contains the cookie "sitename=site1"
4. If the request does not start with "/site1/"

If all of these conditions are met, then the request is rewritten to prepend "/site1/" before the request. I tried having a single set of Conds/Rules that would match (\w+) instead of "site1" in the third Condition, and then refer to %1 in the fourth Condition and in the Rule, but this did not work. I gave up and settled for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the RewriteRules are in your .htaccess file, you need to remove the leading slashes in your match (apache strips them before sending it to mod_rewrite). Does this work?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /site1/js/$1
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /site1/css/$1
```

EDIT: To address the comment:

> Yes, that works, but when I do `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1`, it causes Apache to issue internal server errors. But to me, it seems like that should just be a generic equivalent of the individual rules!

What's happening with that rule is when `/something/` gets rewritten to `/site/something/`, and apache internally redirects, it gets rewritten *again*, to `/site/site/something/`, then again, then again, etc.

You'd need to add a condition to that, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewirteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but when I do `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1`, it causes Apache to issue internal server errors. But to me, it seems like that should just be a generic equivalent of the individual rules!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. This will work for one site, but how would I go about supporting more than one? I tried adding a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /site/` as an additional condition so that it checks the REFERER before rewriting a request. But this doesn't work past the first page, because clicking a link to /page1.htm still displays /page1.htm as the URI, even though it's been rewritten internally to /site/page1.htm. Then the REFERER isn't right when clicking the second link, and the rewrite rule doesn't apply. Any suggestions?

Comment: you probably want `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?mydomain.com` or something instead of checking the referer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up [symlinks](http://learn.clemsonlinux.org/wiki/Symlink), which the rewrite rules will use so your absolute links at the server level can follow the symbolic links to the central site hosting account.